# Google Calendar API Events - timeMin/timeMax not working for a recurring event

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

Using a url of:
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?access_token...&timeMin=2018-06-27T14:43:54.055Z&timeMax=2018-07-04T14:43:54.056Z

This returns events as expected, however there is an event being returned twice, one where the single event was accepted and the other is just the recurring calendar event.

This is the event that shouldn't be returned but was:

```
...
"items": [
{
"kind": "calendar#event",
"status": "confirmed",
"created": "2017-04-20T15:36:37.000Z",
"updated": "2018-05-18T15:36:36.541Z",
"summary": "Meeting",
"creator": {},
"organizer": {},
"start": {
 "dateTime": "2017-04-27T15:00:00-04:00",
 "timeZone": "America/New_York"
},
"end": {
 "dateTime": "2017-04-27T16:00:00-04:00",
 "timeZone": "America/New_York"
},
"recurrence": [
 "RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;BYDAY=4TH"
]
...
```

This is the event that was included that I wanted returned:

```
...
{
 "kind": "calendar#event",
 "status": "confirmed",
 "created": "2017-04-20T15:36:37.000Z",
 "updated": "2018-06-27T14:34:18.544Z",
 "summary": "Meeting",
 "creator": {},
 "organizer": {},
 "start": {
  "dateTime": "2018-06-28T15:00:00-04:00"
 },
 "end": {
  "dateTime": "2018-06-28T16:00:00-04:00"
 },
 "originalStartTime": {
  "dateTime": "2018-06-28T15:00:00-04:00"
 }
 ...
```

Edit: I should add, the reason this is a problem is I just want to list the upcoming events for the week, so it is harder to do if I need to exclude items that aren't actually upcoming. I'm not displaying these in a calendar format where an extra item would just not show.

Comment: What's your expected outcome again? And what are you trying to do?

Comment: List the next 5 upcoming events. Currently, I have to do a check if the event returned is actually in the range I requested with: if(this_startdate.isBetween(startdate, enddate)) { ... }